# What is the proper way to use basic authentication?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am pretty much new to RestSharp and am bit confused about the below two code blocks (numbered).

`var client = new RestClient("url"); // client`

1. `client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password");`
2. `var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
   request.AddHeader("authorization", string.Format("Basic {0}", "username:password"));`

`IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);`

when to use authentication in `client` section and when to use it in `request` section. If we add basic authenticator in client object itself then is it required to bind it in every request that we make?

It would be helpful if someone can explain or direct me to right contents.

Answer (score 1):

> when to use authentication in client section

When you use one client to issue multiple requests that all need the same authorization.

> and when to use it in request section.

When you want to issue a single request that requires authorization.

> If we add basic authenticator in client object itself then is it required to bind it in every request that we make?

No.

See also [Authenticators on RestSharp's GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Authenticators).